# The mathematical approach to the infinity in calculus

Tags: calculus, limits, infinity

Although it is a more philosophical phenomenon rather than mathematical one, the question of the infinity in the study of limit is interesting for me.
If there is no limit of the infinity why we define the fact that limit in the infinity can exist? For example:

$ \lim_{x \rightarrow  0 }  \frac{1}{|x|} = \infty $

As can be seen in the example above, the limit exists even we get the answer as infinity.

Comment: A bit unclear, but when we say a limit "exists" we mean it exists and is a real number.  $\infty$ isn't a real number.

Comment: Do you mean that limit in the infinity doesn't exist?

Comment: Very often, we use infinity as an answer to a limit to assist us in curve behavior. (Like end behavior). In terms of using limits in algebra, infinity is not accepted because if you accept infinity as an answer, a lot of limit laws do not work. For example: The limit of a product is the product of the limits, fails if you allow infinity as a possible answer to a limit

Comment: @TarlanAhad Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

The following

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow  0 }  \frac{1}{|x|} = \infty$$

is **just a symbolic way** to say that, assuming $x$ values sufficiently near to $0$, we can make the expression $\frac{1}{|x|} $ arbitrarly larger than every assigned quantity $M \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I know the concept of Limit in calculus... I want to know the answer to the question that if we obtain the answer as infinity, does the limit of expression exist? If No, why?

Comment: @TarlanAhad Yes it is addressed/defined as a possibile limit, what I mean is that $\infty$ is just a symbol to express what I wrote (i.e. a quantity arbitrarly large) and not a value that is reached.

Comment: @TarlanAhad Sorry but I can't know your level of knowledge by the OP thus it can be that I wrote something very trivial for you, in this case please let me know that.

Comment: The real problem that creates a dilemma in my thoughts is the rule of limit. Your answer to the question is "Yes, exists". How can I prove the theorem that limit of infinity exists in somewhere? For myself, I use the fact that the parallel lines intersect in the infinity.
[Train tracks in the infinity](https://goo.gl/5yAn72)

Comment: @TarlanAhad The point is indeed that is purely a definition and $\infty$ is just a symbol. Once you have defined it (and the definition is somewhat arbitrarly), you can ask if for a specific expression it exists or not.